# I want to change the arrangement of several branches so that both grow from a common starting point, rather than one from the other

Tags: git, github

I am still learning how to use git and I got into a serious problem.

I created and switched to a new branch using **git checkout -b branch01** and added some files in it using **git add .** and I again created a new branch and added another files in it.

Now when I am pushing the files in github, the branch 2 is having files of branch 1 as well and I want only branch 2 to have its own files specified rather than any other branch.

Can anyone please help me out in fixing this problem? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You should write your commands or at least show the graph, because situation is not much clear...

Comment: You went from branch `A -> B` and then later from branch `B -> C`. When you create a new branch it needs to be created from something, if you don't specify this, then the current HEAD is being used.

Comment: Did you commit between `git add .` and `git checkout -b branch02`? That's a very important distinction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best command for flinging branches around like this is `git rebase --onto`. In fact, your case is exactly this one from the [`git rebase` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase):

> Another example of `--onto` option is to rebase part of a branch. If we have the following situation:
>
> ```
>                         H---I---J topicB
>                        /
>               E---F---G  topicA
>              /
> A---B---C---D  master
> ```
>
> then the command
>
> ```
> git rebase --onto master topicA topicB
> ```
>
> would result in:
>
> ```
>              H'--I'--J'  topicB
>             /
>             | E---F---G  topicA
>             |/
> A---B---C---D  master
> ```

Where `topicA` is your "branch 1", `topicB` is your "branch 2", and `master` is their common base (where you branched "branch 1" from originally.

Personally speaking, however, if the number of commits to want to remove from "branch 2" is small, I'd simply `git rebase -i master` from that branch and just delete the commits I didn't want from that branch's history.